# asp.net core windows authentication + own database authorization on slow network

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, windows-authentication

### SITUATION

I have a database where I have usernames and their linked permissions and code that works with it. Think of it as blackbox that gives me user's permissions as an `Enumerable` of `enum` values when I supply username. I need to use it.

I also have an *ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application* that needs to use *Windows authentication* and *Custom Authorization* based on those permissions.

I want to store those permissions for a minute (or ten) because the network is unreliable and querying for user's permissions every time takes a long time and they don't change that frequently. I can't do anything about the speed, I have to work with it.

I have an `AuthorizeAttribute` implementations where I specify a list of permissions (enum values) that user needs to have to get to the action in a controller.

To be more specific I have an older *.net framework asp.net MVC application* where I go around this problem by having my own custom principal with my list of permissions and saving this principal in a cookie.

I'm slowly learning asp.net core and when I started reading about authorization and authentication in it, it was enough to make my head spin from information overload.

### SUMMARY

I have a list of user's permissions that I need to store for some time and don't know what to do make my own custom authorization happen.

*I what I currently have is probably not going to work for me in ASP.NET core MVC application and can't find viable option before getting overloaded by the myriad of options available.*

**What I need is a push in right direction written in simple language (for an idiot) in a direction to look into to make my requirements work.**

### CURRENT (NOT IDEAL) SOLUTION IN ASP.NET FRAMEWORK MVC

Example of what currently somehow works in .net framework asp.net mvc, but is probably far from ideal:

- in `global.asax` override `WindowsAuthentication_onAuthenticate`, where I check if there is a cookie with the user's data and the user is authenticated.

  If the user is authenticated but there is no cookie, create a principal (containing the user's permissions) and serialize and encryt it to `FormsAuthenticationTicket` to the cookie.
- in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` get data from the encrypted cookie and set it up in the `HttpContext.Current.User` as the principal.
- The authorize attribute is then just going to take the array of specified permissions and check in `HttpContext.Current.User` if the user has them.

**Can someone recommend me how to narrow my search for a viable solution (or a viable solution)?**